# Browser notifications API doesn't work in Stack snippet

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-snippets

In the SO answer below, I've inserted working code that demonstrates the Notification API. While it [works on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ziwod/1/edit?html,js,output), it doesn't seem to work on SO, possibly because the identifier of the window that generates is the empty string. The code requests permission to display notifications, but it is never granted.

[Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example/13328513#13328513)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for bringing this up. Stack Snippets uses `HTML5 iframe sandboxing` in order to remain secure and prevent malicious code from hurting our users. This sandboxing prevents such actions as `window` access and notifications. This is therefore by design.